# Should I indent when I write just a short sentence?

Tags: style, resume

I'm writing a curriculum vitae and in **Special skills** section I wrote as the following:

**8- Special skills**

I have the following skills:

- C++
- Objective-C

Should I indent "I have the following skills" line to be exactly above the dots or not?

Comment: What do you do in other sections (that don't have bulleted lists)?  That is, if the list weren't there, would your introductory sentence be consistent with the rest of your CV?

Comment: Your line "I have the following skills:" is superfluous. Cut it.

Comment: @Neil Fein: I object to you commentifying this on the grounds that "it doesn't answer the question." I think it cuts the Gordian knot.  Any other answer is a waste of everyone's time.  CVs should NEVER have useless verbiage, end of discussion.

Comment: What you wrote is absolutely correct -  "I have the following skills" says the same thing as "special skills" above it. But the question is a style issue, not a critique of wording. If you want to discuss this more, I'd be happy do do so; please ping me in chat, or post a thread on Meta.

Answer (score 9):

Keep the style consistent across the whole document, no matter how short the paragraphs. If you indent any paragraph above a list, keep doing so. There are various guidelines if you should indent or not, but none of them are solid rules. Consistency is an ancient rule of style though. So, no rule, but don't make exceptions for short lines.

If you want a recommendation: In recent times, paragraph indent has given way to wider inter-paragraph breaks. OTOH, lists are frequently indented whole - bullets/numbers and list items alike. So, the recommendation would be: don't indent. Keep it flush with all non-list text.